# Access files encrypted with Windows EFS (Encrypting File System) on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, efs

I have a PC with multiple hard drives containing files encrypted with EFS. If I install Linux, is there a way to access these files?

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to find there is a utility included in [ntfs-3g](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) called **ntfsdecrypt** which apparently allows you to decrypt EFS files in Linux.

> ntfsdecrypt decrypts a file from an unmounted device and print the decrypted data on the standard output. It can also update an encrypted file with the encryption key unchanged.

It of course requires you have the keyfile or DRA certificate in order to decrypt.